# Size logo into navbar

Tags: css, header, navbar

So for the longest time now, I've been trying to size my logo into my header/nav bar and I'm really struggling. When I try to change the width or height it doesnt do anything and when I go to look at chrome dev tools, it tells me the image is 500x500. Below I'll insert my code and CSS code I've been using for this specific area.

Code for the image I'm using

```
    <header>
        <navbar>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
        <img id="Logo" src="Sweet_Dreams_Logo-removebg-preview (1).png">
```

Below is the CSS code for the header I've been using.

```
header
    {
        background-color:#4a61c6;;
        position:fixed;
        top: 0; 
        left: 0;
        width: 98.5%;
        padding: 30px 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;    
    }
```

I've tried changing the height, width, padding, margins, sizing, etc but so far nothing has worked. I would like for the logo to be on the side.

Comment: What size do you want it to be? For example have you tried height: 100%?

Comment: I have tried changing the height. I need the image to be around 109px x 40px. Maybe I got the tag wrong in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can size the logo by just adding a height (or/and) width on your image tag:

```css
header
    {
        background-color:#4a61c6;;
        position:fixed;
        top: 0; 
        left: 0;
        width: 98.5%;
        padding: 30px 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;    
    }
    
    .logo {
      height:50px;
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"> 
</head>


<header>
  <navbar>
        <img id="Logo" class="logo" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/modern-flowing-blue-wave-banner-background_1035-19862.jpg">
   </navbar>
</header>
```

Note: I changed the picture because I don't have your local logo. I also changed the location of your style sheet. This should be in the head element